# Do Push Notifications with content-available work for users that have disabled Push Notifications?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm looking into reliable ways of updating an iOS app with content of critical importance, when instructed to do so by a server.

This would have to trigger regardless of the state of the app (foreground, background, not running, etc). Most sources seem to indicate that Push Notifications with the `content-available: 1`parameter are able of doing this.

My question is, what happens if the user either presses Cancel when prompted to allow the app to receive push notifications, or turns them off afterwards ? Is he only not going to receive alerts anymore, or will the push notifications be entirely ignored (including the content update) ? And if so, is there any other iOS feature that would **reliably** allow me to update the app's content (regardless of app state and without the user being able to disable it) ?

This is about iOS 7 and above.

Comment: Yes, the user who selected cancel when the enable push notification prompt is shown, will not receive any push notification payload.

Comment: But you can still use iOS Background App Refresh feature from ios 7 and above: http://www.devfright.com/ios-7-background-app-refresh-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

If user disallows the push notifications , you can not send them the notifications forcefully.

What kind of data you want to update afterwards?

Most of the data can be changed dynamically by web services...

Comment: My use case is: Each user is contacted by me once a year or so, and offered an additional feature within the app. The feature already exists within the app, but the user does not have access to it. I want to remotely and instantly enable that feature. Edit: Since I only need to trigger this once per year per user or so, the previously recommended Background App Refresh would be highly ineffective in terms of network usage, and it would also not enable me to update instantly as I cannot control exactly when it's triggered. How would a web service help me with this ? Thanks for the quick reply.